# Калькулятор не работает с++

Tags: c++, switch

Я недавно начал изучать с++ . сегодня решил сделать калькулятор . работает некорректно . при вводе 2 + 2 выводит 4041 . похоже , что это другая система счисления.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int results;
    char operation;
    std::cout << "Add first number" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> number1;
    std::cout << "Add second number" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> number2;
    std::cout << "Add type of operation" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> operation;
    switch(operation){
        case '+':
            results = number1 + number2;
            std::cout << results;
        case '-':
            results = number1 - number2;
            std::cout << results;
        case '*':
            results = number1 * number2;
            std::cout << results;
        case '/':
            results = number1 / number2;
            std::cout << results;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В дополнение к уже указанному ответу: включайте максимальное количество варнингов! Вы бы сразу обнаружили проблему, если бы скомпилировали с флагами `-Wall -Wextra` (для `g++`)

Comment: также что касается интерфейса для такого кальклятора: почитайте об обратной польской записи (если еще не читали)

Answer (score 4):

Потому что код "проваливается" от одного `case` в другой. и для 2+2 вы выводите четыре результата - сумму, разность, произведение и частное - 4, 0, 4 и 1 :)

Никаких чудеc с какими-то иными системами счисления... Надо не забывать о `break`.

Почитайте, например, [это](https://ravesli.com/urok-65-operator-switch/).